# Coredata fetchRequest breaks if there is nothing stored

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have my coredata set up and saving and fetchRequests work well.  In this case I am fetching the first object saved in 'Item' but if the fetchResult is empty I do not want to call my method 'displayDataInLabel' as if there is nothing in it this method breaks (i'm guessing because the is nothing at 'objectAtIndex:0'

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
    if (_fetchResultsController.fetchedObjects == nil) {
            return;
        }

    else
    [self displayDataInLabel];
}

-(void)displayDataInLabel
{

    Item *thisItem = [_fetchResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"test item %@", thisItem.name);

}
```

Comment: You have answered your own question. Check for the `count` and do something else if it is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient to check for `nil` because the result, even if nothing is found, will still be a valid (empty) array, which is *not* `nil`.

Instead, check if the `count` property of the result is zero.